# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:

Tags: android

I am Developing an app. When i am running the app on api level 21(Lollipop device) app is crashing. And i am getting resource not found exception. but when i checked this resource id in `R.java` resource id is available. please tell me what is the reason.

**CODE**

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.bravoslimo.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/NoTitleStyle" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is r.java

```
public static final int activity_locaton=0x7f03001a;
        public static final int activity_login=0x7f03001b;
        public static final int activity_payment=0x7f03001c;
        public static final int activity_reservation_confirmation=0x7f03001d;
        public static final int activity_splash=0x7f03001e;
        public static final int activity_terms_and_condition=0x7f03001f;
        public static final int center_action_bar_text=0x7f030020;
        public static final int com_facebook_friendpickerfragment=0x7f030021;
        public static final int com_facebook_login_activity_layout=0x7f030022;
        public static final int com_facebook_picker_activity_circle_row=0x7f030023;
```

here is my code

```
package com.bravoslimo.activities;



public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements
        OnAsynTaskFinishedListener {

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        AndroidUtils.getHashKey(SplashActivity.this);
        // Calling the getCountry API

        if (ConnectivityController.isNetworkAvailable(SplashActivity.this)) {

            GetCountryAsynTask countryAsynTask = new GetCountryAsynTask(
                    SplashActivity.this, ConstantsUtils.API_ID,
                    ConstantsUtils.API_KEY);
            countryAsynTask.setOnAsynTaskFinishedListener(this);
            countryAsynTask.execute();
            //startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, TermsAndConditions.class));
            //selectAvtivityToStart();
        } else {
            showAlartDialog();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void OnAsynTaskFinished(String asynTaskName) {


    }


}
```

Log

```
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511): Process: com.bravoslimo, PID: 2511
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bravoslimo/com.bravoslimo.activities.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03001e
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03001e
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2598)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1049)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at com.bravoslimo.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:35)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
03-10 14:35:24.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2511):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: often a clean resolves those issues

Comment: Have you tried Project > Clear or Rebuild project?

Comment: yes i clean the project

Comment: Can you please tell in which line of code are you getting the exception.

Comment: com.bravoslimo.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:35)

Comment: Try to delete everything what's in the gen folder. It will be regenerated at the next start. I had a similar error and this worked for me

Comment: this exception only occur in lollipop devices

Comment: Can you please tell me what's there in that line.

Comment: What resource folder does `activity_splash.xml` live in?

Comment: problem is in the layout of that activity, so even if you rebuild that won't help, check your activity layout remove the error and rebuild again

Comment: Post your layout file here

Comment: Have you tried importing your apps R file? `import com.bravoslimo.activities.R;' or making sure you're not importing the android.R?

Comment: is it working on other API levels?